# CSS vertical line in angularjs treeview

Tags: css, angularjs, treeview

I have been trying to make tree view in angularjs. Frankly speaking, I am very bad in styling have to struggle a lot for simple things. Now I am stuck for a problem where I am trying to align vertical and horizontal lines for tree items.

I have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYmwZL).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Drag and drop angular tree</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/master/src/sortable.js"></script>  
  <style>

div[data-tree-model] ul {
  margin: 0;

  list-style: none; 
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

div[data-tree-model] li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .expanded {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: url("http://cfile23.uf.tistory.com/image/205B973A50C13F4B19D9BD");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .collapsed {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: url("http://cfile23.uf.tistory.com/image/1459193A50C13F4B1B05FB");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .normal {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: url("http://cfile23.uf.tistory.com/image/165B663A50C13F4B196CCA");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

div[data-tree-model] li i, div[data-tree-model] li span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .selected {
  background-color: #aaddff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px 5px;
} 

div[data-tree-model] li::before, div[data-tree-model] li::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -12px;
}

div[data-tree-model] li::before {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    top: 9px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

div[data-tree-model] li::after {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

div[data-tree-model] ul > li:last-child::after {
    height: 8px;
}

div[data-tree-model] li:fisrt-child::after {
 height: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <!-- <div>{{roleList}}</div></br> -->
      <div class="clt"
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-id="mytree"
      data-tree-model="roleList"
      data-node-id="roleId"
      data-node-label="roleName"
      data-node-children="children" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
(function(){

  //angular module
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview', 'ui.sortable']);

  //test controller
  myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){

    //test tree model 1
    $scope.roleList1 = [
        { "roleName" : "User", "roleId" : "role1", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subUser1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subUser2", "roleId" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Admin", "roleId" : "role2", "id":"01", "children" : [] },

        { "roleName" : "Guest", "roleId" : "role3", "id":"02", "children" : [] }
      ];

    //test tree model 2
    $scope.roleList2 = [
        { "roleName" : "User", "roleId" : "role1", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subUser1", "roleId" : "role11", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subUser2", "roleId" : "role12", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Admin", "roleId" : "role2", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subAdmin1", "roleId" : "role11", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subAdmin2", "roleId" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subAdmin2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Guest", "roleId" : "role3", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subGuest1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subGuest2", "roleId" : "role12", "collapsed" : true, "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "Banned Area", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subGuest2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "Parent":"Banned Area" ,"children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subGuest2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "Parent":"Banned Area", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]}
      ];



    //roleList1 to treeview
    $scope.roleList = $scope.roleList2;

  });

})();



(function ( angular ) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'angularTreeview', [] ).directive( 'treeModel', ['$compile', function( $compile ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
                //tree id
                var treeId = attrs.treeId;

                //tree model
                var treeModel = attrs.treeModel;

                //node id
                var nodeId = attrs.nodeId || 'id';

                //node label
                var nodeLabel = attrs.nodeLabel || 'label';

                //children
                var nodeChildren = attrs.nodeChildren || 'children';

scope.sortableOptions = {
  connectWith: ".apps-container",
  update: function(event, ui) {         
          var index = ui.item.sortable.index;
                    var dropindex = ui.item.sortable.dropindex;
                    var dropTargetModel = ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel;
                    var dragModel = ui.item.sortable.model;         
    //debugger

  }
};
                //tree template
            var template =
                '<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container" ng-model="'+ treeModel+'">' +
                    '<li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + treeModel + '">' +
                        '<i class="collapsed" data-ng-show="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)"></i>' +
                        '<i class="expanded" data-ng-show="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && !node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)"></i>' +
                        '<i class="normal" data-ng-hide="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length"></i> ' +
                        '<span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeLabel(node)">{{node.' + nodeLabel + '}}</span>' +
                        '<div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-id="' + treeId + '" data-tree-model="node.' + nodeChildren + '" data-node-id=' + nodeId + ' data-node-label=' + nodeLabel + ' data-node-children=' + nodeChildren + '></div>' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>';


                //check tree id, tree model
                if( treeId && treeModel ) {

                    //root node
                    if( attrs.angularTreeview ) {

                        //create tree object if not exists
                        scope[treeId] = scope[treeId] || {};

                        //if node head clicks,
                        scope[treeId].selectNodeHead = scope[treeId].selectNodeHead || function( selectedNode ){

                            //Collapse or Expand
                            selectedNode.collapsed = !selectedNode.collapsed;
                        };

                        //if node label clicks,
                        scope[treeId].selectNodeLabel = scope[treeId].selectNodeLabel || function( selectedNode ){

                            //remove highlight from previous node
                            if( scope[treeId].currentNode && scope[treeId].currentNode.selected ) {
                                scope[treeId].currentNode.selected = undefined;
                            }

                            //set highlight to selected node
                            selectedNode.selected = 'selected';

                            //set currentNode
                            scope[treeId].currentNode = selectedNode;
                        };
                    }

                    //Rendering template.
                    element.html('').append( $compile( template )( scope ) );
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
})( angular );
</script>
</html>
```

I am trying to align vertical lines, first it should be touched to folder open-close images and at the corners. Second there is open end at first child. i want to make it like ,

[image]

Please help, how can i achieve this. any suggestions would be gladly accepted. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
div[data-tree-model] li::before {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    top: 9px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

by

```
div[data-tree-model] li::before {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    top: 8px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

and you'll get
[image] instead of [image]

Is that what you expect ?

Comment: Exactly this is what i expected. Thanks.  I would be very much thankful if you please help to get the corner setting for fist child (Users) , as given in picture. Also the vertical lines, should be touched to folder open-close images.